# Can we add multiple font file mappings for the single font family name in fonts.xml for android 5.0 (lollipop)?

Tags: android, fonts, android-5.0-lollipop, android-fonts

e.g.

```
IF case 1 happens     
   map arial to sans-serif
ELSE
   map arial to serif
```

or another possibility is

```
only when case 3 happens 
   map arial to sans-serif
```

Basically i would like to know if we can add conditional statements in fonts.xml?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean change the typefont dinammically? I mean depends of something you use one font or not?

Comment: to give you more insight, I would like to set the font mappings in fonts.xml such a way that for few products/application if i set arial as font family it should use sans-serif whereas for other application it should use serif.